# Как в цикле отделить значение?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, коллекции

У меня есть такой код:

```
import socket

addrlist = []
buf = []

def listurl():
    global buf
    handle = open('ad.txt')
    for x in handle:
        buf.append(x)
    handle.close()
    buf = map(lambda buf: buf.strip(), buf)
    buf = list(buf)

def getipforlist(ip):
    global addrlist
    temp = socket.gethostbyname(str(ip))
    temp = temp.split('.')
    addrlist += list(temp)

listurl()
for x in buf:
    getipforlist(x)

numbers = [int(c) for c in addrlist]
print('http://' + '.'.join(map(hex, numbers)))
```

В конце своей работы он выдает вот такое значение:

```
http://0x8c.0x52.0x76.0x4.0x1f.0xd.0x48.0x24.0x68.0x19.0x5.0xe
```

Но мне надо чтобы он выдавал по каждые 4 элемента.
Пример:

```
http://0x8c.0x52.0x76.0x4
http://0x1f.0xd.0x48.0x24
http://0x68.0x19.0x5.0xe

numbers = [140, 82, 118, 4, 31, 13, 72, 36, 104, 25, 4, 14]
```

Как это можно сделать? Поделить на такие элементы?

Comment: Добавьте пример значения в `numbers` в вопрос

Comment: Добавил значение.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Делим список на списки по 4 элемента:

```
all_numbers = [140, 82, 118, 4, 31, 13, 72, 36, 104, 25, 5, 14]

for i in range(0, len(all_numbers), 4):
    numbers = all_numbers[i: i + 4]
    print('http://' + '.'.join(map(hex, numbers)))
```

Консоль:

```
http://0x8c.0x52.0x76.0x4
http://0x1f.0xd.0x48.0x24
http://0x68.0x19.0x5.0xe
```